# bootstrap right block over left block on mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have 2 blocks using bootstrap grid system.

On mobile view, I want the right block above the left one. The right block should also occupy 100% width of the screen.

My code so far:

```
<style>
.block {
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 25px;
}
.block2 {
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
</style>

<div class="container checkoutform">
<form class="row mx-n2">
  <div class="col-sm-8 px-2">
    <div class="block">
        
        <!-- code -->


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 px-2">
    <div class="block2">
        
        <!-- code -->

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 100%;` to the `.block2` and `.block` style rules.
As well, try to switch the places of the `block` and `block2` div elements.
It should be looking like that:

The CSS:

```
.block {
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
.block2 {
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 100%;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="container checkoutform">
<form class="row mx-n2">
  <div class="col-sm-8 px-2">
      <div class="col-sm-4 px-2">
    <div class="block2">
        <!-- code -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 px-2">
    <div class="block">
        <!-- code -->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Please let me know if it worked!